# How to use Angular factories to persist state between Angular controllers

Tags: angularjs, state, factories

I wish to maintain user state between different Angular controllers.  Am using a JWT for authentication and and can use this to return User attributes securely from the server on each controller but that is a complete round robin each time I do a controller switch.

So I added the following method to my UserFactory:

```
function getLocalUser() {
  var localUser = {};
  return {
     isSet:isSet,
     get:get,
     set:set
  };
  function isSet(){
      return (Object.keys(localUser).length > 0)
  };
  function get() {
     return localUser
  };
  function set(U){
     Object.keys(U).forEach(function (c,i,a){
     localUser[c] = U[c];
   })
 }
}
```

The UserController logs in so:

```
function login(username, password) {
  UserFactory.login( username, password).then(function success(response) {
    $scope.vm.loggedInUser = response.data.user;
    $scope.vm.username  = null;
    $scope.vm.password  = null;
    UserFactory.getLocalUser().set($scope.vm.loggedInUser);
  },handleError);
}
```

This clearly works but when I move to the next controller:

```
    $scope.vm = {};
    // initialize
    if (UserFactory.getLocalUser().isSet) {
      $scope.vm.loggedInUser = UserFactory.getLocalUser().get();
    } else {
      UserFactory.getUser().then(function success(response) {
        $scope.vm.loggedInUser = response.data;
      });
    }
```

the call to

```
UserFactory.getLocalUser().isSet
```

initializes var localUser = {} again and of course it is empty.

I am a wannabe here so be kind

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to move the initialization of your `localUser` object (`var localUser = {}`) out of the function `getLocalUser()` so that it happens only once. If you're still stuck, show all of the code for your `UserFactory` so someone can help further.

Comment: I think you would better use an angular Service, with the variable 'localUser' as one of its attributes (thus it would be initialized only once).

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it. But looks like you'r creating a reference from userFactory to userController. So when userController is destroyed the reference is pointing to nothing.

You need to create a copy of the object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

The betetr solution would be to move you login functionality to userFactory. When userFactory would hold the data and not userCOntroller